# Is there a way to delete or clear a register?

Tags: registers

For example, if I have too many registers and would like to get rid of some of them, is there a way to do that?

I realize that quitting the emacs session will clear all registers, but is there a way to do that within a session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function `set-register` (`C-h f`):

> `set-register` is a compiled Lisp function in `register.el`.
>
> `(set-register REGISTER VALUE)`
>
> Set contents of Emacs register named `REGISTER` to `VALUE`.  Returns `VALUE`.
>
> See the documentation of the variable `register-alist` for possible `VALUE`s.

And (elisp) [Registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Registers.html):

```
 -- Function: set-register reg value
     This function sets the contents of register REG to VALUE.  A
     register can be set to any value, but the other register functions
     expect only certain data types.  The return value is VALUE.
```

So `(set-register ?a nil)` resets/clears register `a`.

You can also reset registers using `register-alist`.  E.g., to reset registers `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```lisp
(setq register-alist  (append '((?a) (?b) (?c)) register-alist))
```

---

BTW. How did I find function `set-register` and variable `register-alist`? *Apropos* (e.g. command `apropos`) is your friend.

(Actually, I just use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), which provides [apropos completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Apropos_Completions). I typed `C-h f register S-TAB`.)

Comment: NB: Both the methods above clear the registers.  The second method grows `register-alist` - so there will be two register `a`s and so on - both the registers will have `nil` values.  Also, in the register preview wiindow, the values are displayed as `Garbage`.  (Thanks for the answer.  Just wanted to make a note of the above).

Comment: Yes. It's an *alist*. If you really want to remove the existing elements from it you can do that instead. But you don't have to. And no, both the `?a` registers will not have `nil` values. The more recent alist entry shadows the older one, which still has the original value. Shadowing the older alist element means that register `?a` is empty - its value is `nil`. Try `(get-register ?a)`, with `register-alist` = `((?a) (?a . "aaa"))`. It returns `nil`, which means that register `?a` has no contents.

Comment: Yes, both are not `nil` - the older `a` has the older value.  In the register preview window, two `a` registers are shown and both have a `Garbage` value.  I am unable to edit my comment above to make this correction.

Comment: No, neither has a garbage value. Only the first one exists as a register (it is the only one seen by `get-register`), and it is empty - has no garbage content - it has no content at all. The problem is in the code for register previewing: It should not show content of `Garbage:`. I've filed Emacs [bug #37155](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=37155) for this. Try `list-registers` or `view-register` and you'll see a correct presentation. The previewing code is faulty.

Comment: +1 for filing a bug.